# AJAX sent parameters with 200 status code OK, but I can't get values in success function - AJAX wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

jQuery ajax call

```
    $(".filter-bar li").click(function(e){
        const termID = +jQuery(e.target).attr("id"); // Get id to send it to url

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: ajax_query.url,
            data: {
                "action": "get_term_id",
                "tax_id": termID,
                "security": ajax_query.nonce
            },
            sucess: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("Succeed")
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Faild")
            }
        })
    })
```

PHP code

```
add_action("wp_ajax_get_term_id", "get_term_id");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_term_id", "get_term_id");

function get_term_id(){
    $id = isset($_POST['tax_id']) ? $_POST['tax_id']: 'Empty' ;
    return $id;
    wp_die();  
}
```

[this in network debugging status code is 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK977.png)

I'm trying to get the value from URL in my DOM but gives me undefined array key "tax_id" in functions.php

Comment: WP AJAX actions need to `echo` their output, not `return` it. You can try looking at using `wp_send_json()` or looking at how Wordpress uses `wp_send_json()` to send output.

Comment: @TPaone I tried to use `echo` and `wp_send_json()` but still problem.

Comment: I'm trying to get the value from URL in my DOM but gives me undefined array key "tax_id" in functions.php

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the  problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to  get `tax_id` appear in console

Comment: That's not what I've asked for. Does `$_POST` even contain that key? How does the request look like?

Comment: yes it has, i attached a screenshot for network debugging 
`Request Method: POST
 || Status Code: 200`

Comment: And what does` $_POST` contain? Please don't guess, dump it

Comment: in `functions.php` contain nothing althought already sent to URL

Comment: If `$_POST` contains "nothing" (which would be really strange, as this should at least be an empty array), it's obvious that you cannot use `$_POST['tax_id']`